# Phoenix create SecondaryIndex timeout

Tags: timeout, apache-phoenix, secondary-indexes

I'm new to Phoenix and encountered a problem. Firstly, I created a table with 30000000 records by java on Phoenix. Then, I want to create a phoenix global secondIndex to the table. But, when the program runed for 10 minutes, the java client throws SQLTimeoutException. I don't know why, Please help me.

```html
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Operation timed out.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$15.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:376)
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:804)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:720)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.RoundRobinResultIterator.getIterators(RoundRobinResultIterator.java:176)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.RoundRobinResultIterator.next(RoundRobinResultIterator.java:91)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.UpsertCompiler$2.execute(UpsertCompiler.java:810)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.DelegateMutationPlan.execute(DelegateMutationPlan.java:31)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.PostIndexDDLCompiler$1.execute(PostIndexDDLCompiler.java:124)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.updateData(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2805)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.buildIndex(MetaDataClient.java:1153)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createIndex(MetaDataClient.java:1462)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateIndexCompiler$1.execute(CreateIndexCompiler.java:85)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:340)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:328)
        at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:326)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1369)
        at cc.xidian.PhoenixOperation.PhoenixSQLOperation.createSecondIndexHintForGeoHashValueLongOfTable(PhoenixSQLOperation.java:1713)
        at cc.xidian.MainTest.GeoHashMainTest.main(GeoHashMainTest.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
CreateSecondIndex-Time: 602708
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the index using the async option.